# Laravel Task Scheduler across multiple servers without overlap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am wondering if anyone has any experience with making the Laravel Task Scheduler work without overlapping across multiple servers.

**To put it in context:** I have 3 API servers behind a load balancer.  I know the task scheduler allows for the withoutOverlap flag on a single server, but how could I use that same principal across all of my servers?   I want only 1 server to run the scheduled tasks and have the other 2 servers not run them.

As far as I can tell, my options are:

**Remove the crontab from 2 of the servers.**  I have my servers automated and would rather not remove the crontab job from any of the servers because that would complicate my automated builds.

**Write a package that uses the DB to limit the tasks to only the first server that runs.** 
I could do this, but am wondering if it has already been done (cannot find anything on google)

Any advice?

Comment: @Daniel What have you done? I am in the same situation.

Comment: @hedi I ended up just setting the cron job to run on one server. Not ideal but it works

Comment: I had the same problem, but rolled my own solution in the end - couldn't find anything online at the time. The main problem with using the database is that scaling becomes an issue - I had 7 servers executing 50+ commands - ended up getting a lot of failed database queries. Staggering the execution got me a bit further. My eventual solution involved each console scheduler executing a Closure which sequentially stepped through commands in a list. Bit awkward, but brought the number of commands hitting the database at once right down without compromising the uniformity, parallelism or failover

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is available out of the box as of Laravel 5.6+.

Per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server) you would implement it with the `onOneServer` function, like so...

```
$schedule->command('report:generate')
            ->fridays()
            ->at('17:00')
            ->onOneServer();
```

Answer (score 4):

One guy implement it already. check out this composer package
https://packagist.org/packages/jdavidbakr/multi-server-event

Answer (score 3):

How about add a variable on .env file `(SERVER=1; SERVER=2; SERVER=3)` then on Kernel.php, just add a condition `if (env('SERVER') == 1) {}`. Simple but it works.

Comment: what if server 1 goes down? how can I trigger other living servers to do the scheduled jobs automatically?